# Sharepoint 2013 Discussion Board OOB Webpart on a publishing page causes the Edit Page functionality not to work/function after publishing the page

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, xslt-list-view-web-part, discussion-board

Discussion Board OOB Webpart (xsltListViewWebpart) on a publishing page causes the Edit Page functionality not to work/function after publishing the page.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Site Collection (Publishing Portal)
2. Go to Manage Site Features in Site settings. Activate "Team Collaboration Lists"
   Feature.
3. Go to Site Contents and add a new Discussion Board list.
4. Go to Pages library and add a webpart page.
5. On the Webpart page add Discussion board (list) webpart (choose the new discussion
   board from Apps)
6. Check in the page and publish it.
7. Observe that the Edit option is still existing on the top right corner ribbon on the page.
8. Click Edit Option from the ribbon and it fails to get the Page in edit mode.
9. At this point we can only edit if we explicitly checkout the page.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recognize this as an issue and at this point cannot make a fix to the edit logix for the page as it introduces substantial risk to the product stability, instead suggested to go with the workaround "The user has to explicitly checkout the page and then click Edit Page."